# Transit visa in Bangkok for a Sri Lankan

Tags: sri-lankan-citizens, bkk

I'm a Sri Lankan who is traveling from Brisbane to Sri Lanka. I have a 2 hour transit visa in BKK (Bangkok Airport). My both flights (from BNE to BKK and BKK to CMB) are Thai Airways flights. Do I need to have a transit visa for staying 2 hours in Bangkok airport? I have a Sri Lankan passport.